# How to create a non-static HTML table header and rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have two arrays, and I'd like to create a table with dynamic header cells (from the first array called `subjects`) and iteratively add contents (from the second array called `examscores`) in table rows with respect to the table header value.

Desired outcome is ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bp219nL0/1/)):

[image]

The erb code is:

```
 <table width="100%" border="1">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th rowspan="2" scope="col">NAME</th>
 <th colspan="<%= @subjects_by_class.size %>" scope="col">Subjects/Scores</th>
 <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Total</th>
 <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Average</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <% @subjects_by_class.each do |s| %>
 <th> <%= s.name %></th>
 <% end %>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <% @examscore.each do |ex| %>
 <tr>

 <td><%= get_student_name_by_id(ex.student_id) %></td>

 <% @subjects_by_class.each do |ss| %>
 <% @examscore.each do |ii| %>

 <% if ss.id == ex.subject_id %>
 <td> <%= i.total %> </td>
 <% break %>
 <% end %>

 <% end %>
 <% end %>

 <td><%= sum_student_totalscore(ex.student_id, year_id) %> </td>
 <td><%= avg_student_totalscore(ex.student_id, year_id) %></td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

The output I get is ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwhLLabn/)):

[image]

A new `tr` is created under `Maths` subject instead of a new `td` for `Arts` subject, and this results in `Average` `td` being distorted.

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just look at this section of your code:

```
<% @examscore.each do |ex| %>
 <tr>
```

You create a new line for each @examscore, and you have 4 of those (1 per user/subject, so you end up with 4 lines of course).

Your tbody should be something like this:

```
<tbody>
  <% @students.each do |student| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= student.name %></td>
      <% @subjects_by_class.each do |subject| %>
        <% @examscore.each do |score| %>
          <% if score.subject_id == subject.id && score.student_id == student.id %>
            <td><%= score.total %></td>
            <% break %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <td><%= sum_student_totalscore(student.id, year_id) %> </td>
      <td><%= avg_student_totalscore(student.id, year_id) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

It's a bit strange that you only care about the year in your totals

Also you could improve things a little bit by having a method in your Student class that returns an array of scores for a given year/list of subjects

```
# Returns an array of scores for the given year
def scores(year, subject_ids)
  subject_ids.map do |subject_id|
    # find score for year & the given subject_id
  end
end
```

This way your body would become

```
<tbody>
  <% @students.each do |student| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= student.name %></td>
      <% @scores = student.scores(year_id, @subjects_by_class) %>
      <% @scores.each do |score| %>
        <td><%= score.total %></td>
      <% end %>
      <% scores_total = @scores.sum(&:total) %>
      <td><%= scores_total %> </td>
      <td><%= scores_total / @scores.size.to_f %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

which I found more clear, but it could be further improved with decorators for instance.